# Cython memoryviews: wrapping c function with array parameter to pass numpy array

Tags: python, c, numpy, cython, memoryview

I am trying to use Cython to wrap c function with an array parameter (`quick_sort()`), so I can pass a numpy array to it. I've searched the documentation, SO and web for a working, minimal example but didn't find it. I've tried several possibilities but without any progress, so please help me to figure it out. Here are my files:

**quicksort.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void quick_sort (int* a, int n) {
    int i, j, p, t;
    if (n < 2)
        return;
    p = a[n / 2];
    for (i = 0, j = n - 1;; i++, j--) {
        while (a[i] < p)
            i++;
        while (p < a[j])
            j--;
        if (i >= j)
            break;
        t = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = t;
    }
    quick_sort(a, i);
    quick_sort(a + i, n - i);
}
```

**quicksort.h**

```
void quick_sort (int* a, int n);
```

**quicksort.pxd**

```
cdef extern from "quicksort.h":
    void quick_sort (int[:] a, int n)
```

**cy_quicksort.pyx**

```
cimport quicksort

def quicksort_c(int[:] a):
    quicksort.quick_sort(a, a.size)
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name='quicksort cython',
    ext_modules=cythonize("*.pyx"),
)
```

When I'm running `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` command, it returns the following error:

```
cy_quicksort.c:1362:14: error: passing '__Pyx_memviewslice' to parameter of
      incompatible type 'int *'
  quick_sort(__pyx_v_a, __pyx_t_3);
             ^~~~~~~~~
./quicksort.h:1:23: note: passing argument to parameter 'a' here
void quick_sort (int* a, int n);
```

What I want to achieve is to compile this and be able to run for example:

```
import numpy as np
from cy_quicksort import quicksort_c
a = np.array(range(9, 0, -1), dtype=np.int32)
quicksort_c(a)
```

Thanks in advance for Your time!

---

#### Edit:

After changes suggested by DavidW in **quicksort.pxd**, **cy_quicksort.pyx** and changing the **setup.py** file into the following form, it's working as intended.

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension

sourcefiles = ['cy_quicksort.pyx', 'quicksort.c']

extensions = [Extension("cy_quicksort", sourcefiles)]

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions)
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is mainly in "quicksort.pxd" - the definition needs to match that in quicksort.h:

```
cdef extern from "quicksort.h":
    void quick_sort (int* a, int n)
```

(`[:]` defines it as a memoryview instead, which is a Cythony invention and can't be cast directly to a pointer, as your error says).

You then need to get a pointer from the memoryview in "cy_quicksort.pyx"

```
def quicksort_c(int[::1] a):
    quicksort.quick_sort(&a[0], a.size) # get address of first element
```

I've changed the input parameter to `[::1]` to specify that the elements must be continuous in memory, which I think is what quicksort expects.

(Note - untested, but reasonably simple so should work!)

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. With Your fixes it compiles, however when I try to `import cy_quicksort` it returns `ImportError: dlopen(./cy_quicksort.so, 2): Symbol not found: _quick_sort Referenced from: ./cy_quicksort.so Expected in: flat namespace in ./cy_quicksort.so`. Do You know what can be the issue?

Comment: You need to make sure quicksort.c is compiled and linked when the module is generated. Have a look at http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#configuring-the-c-build (the bottom example). I think you need to do `sourcefiles = ['cy_quicksort.pyx', 'quicksort.c']` and then follow the rest of the example given in the link. link

Comment: Thank You very much, now it's working! I would spend hours trying to figure that out by myself... I've edited my question to add working setup.py for any potential reader.

Comment: Talking about complicated syntax... :D But it works. It took me quite a while to find this information. Thanks for the great answer  and explanation.

Comment: @Azerila you probably haven't told Cython about the C function you're trying to use (so it's assuming the function is a Python function that takes Python objects)