# Cython example for sending array/vector to a c++ script

Tags: python, c++, cython, memoryview

Say we have a 1 dimensional numpy array or list that we use as an input to a function, i.e.,  func(np.array[1.5, 2.5, 3.5]), where this function comes from a wrapped c++ class and our goal is to print the values of this array or vector inside the c++ script.

However, I don't know how to define the c++ function for this matter and specify it in the pyx file. And wanted to ask if you can share a snippet as simple as having the above functionality, where **low latency** is of most importance.

Basically, on the c++ side I want to do:

```
void func (/* where I don't what to write */) {

std::cout <<  array_[0] << std::endl; // which prints 1.5 (since np.array[1.5, 2.5, 3.5][0] was 1.5)
std::cout <<  array_[1] << std::endl; // which prints 2.5 (since np.array[1.5, 2.5, 3.5][1] was 2.5)
std::cout <<  array_[2] << std::endl; // which prints 3.5 (since np.array[1.5, 2.5, 3.5][2] was 3.5)
}
```

It seems memoryviews offer a possible solution that also has low latency, however looking at Cython's [documentation about memoryviews](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html), I'm quite confused.

The example [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503828/cython-memoryviews-wrapping-c-function-with-array-parameter-to-pass-numpy-array) mentions (int* a, int n) as the argument of the above function, but I didn't understant what a and n are about and how do I sill index the array on teh c++ side. And finally writing the pyx mirror is also unclear to me.

I would appreciate if anyone could give a very simple snippet example for such c++ function and it's pyx counterpart. Any suggestion other than memoryviews that is not slow is also greatly welcome:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `a` is a variable that contains a pointer to zero or more `int`.
- `n` is a the number of values that `a` contains.

You can index `a` using the standard C++ array access syntax `a[i]`. Make sure `i < n`.

The C++ header would then look like:

```
void func(int *a, int n);
```

The .pyx file would be something like

```
cdef extern from "myheader.hpp":
    void func(int *a, int n)

def func_wrapper(int[::1] mview):
    func(&mview[0], mview.shape[0])
```

You will need to compile it [in the usual way](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#configuring-the-c-build) being sure to list both your Cython source file and your C source file (the .cpp file, not the header) in the sources list.

Comment: Thanks. since the array I wanted to access on c++ side has float numbers I changed it to (float *a, int n) and (float[::1] mview), which worked. I hope it was ok to do this.

Comment: Yes - that's the right way to handle floats instead of ints